# Spring Security Logout

Tags: java, spring, security, logout

I ran into trouble with Spring Security. I´m able to login but not to logout (at least not as expected).

After login, I will be redirected to /secure/home.xhtml <- this works fine and as expected. But I´m not able to logout through #{request.contextPath}/logout. (I have changed the logout url in the spring security config, but I also tried it with the default one) There is always a 404.

Here the code so far:

index.xhtm <- works fine

```
<form method="POST" id="loginForm" action="#{request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" class="form-signin" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username" class="control-label">#{bundle["login.username"]}</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="input-block-level form-control"
                       placeholder="#{bundle['label.username']}" required="true" tabindex="1" />
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password" class="control-label">#{bundle["login.password"]}</label>
                <input type="password" class="input-block-level form-control" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2"
                       placeholder="#{bundle['label.password']}" required="true" />
                <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" tabindex="3" class="btn btn-success btn-block">#{bundle["login.action"]}</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
        </form>
```

spring-security.xhtml, http conf

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" >
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="hasAnyRole('USER','ADMIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
        <!--<security:access-denied-handler error-page="/404.xhtml" />-->
        <security:form-login 
            login-page="/index.xhtml" 
            default-target-url="/secure/home.xhtml" 
            authentication-failure-url="/index.xhtml?error"
            username-parameter="username" 
            password-parameter="password" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/index.xhtml?logout" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
        <security:csrf />
    </security:http>
```

This is the way I tried to implement the logout regarding to other answers here on stackoverflow:

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/logout">logout</a>
                    <h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/logout">Logout</h:outputLink>
```

But both links doesn´t work. I get the 404. I also read that you should replace request.contextPath with pageContext.request.contextPath but that did not work too. (instead of localhost:8080/myContext/logout the link will redirect me to localhost:8080/logout)

A tutorial showed me, that logging out can be also implemented with this:

```
<form method="POST" id="loginForm" action="#{request.contextPath}/logout" class="form-signin" autocomplete="off">
                        <button type="submit" tabindex="3" class="btn btn-success btn-block">#{bundle["logout.action"]}</button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="#{_csrf.parameterName}" value="#{_csrf.token}" />
                    </form>
```

At beginning it seemed to solve my problem, but after adding more pages to the secure section, for example "profile.xhtml", I came accross the undesireable behaviour that I get logged out after the page is loaded.
So if I add the logout-form as above in my home.xhtml, it seems that I get logged out even if I do not click on logout. If I refresh the page, I will be redirected to index.xhtml (login) even if I did NOT click on Logout. So If I click on the link to profile.xhtml I will naturally be redirected to index.xhtml as spring thinks I logged out. Without this form, I stay logged in, but not able to logout! It´s a mess!

Ah and if I click on the logout button on the form, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 403 - Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?

type Status report

messageExpected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?

descriptionAccess to the specified resource has been forbidden.
```

I have really no idea whats wrong with my config :(!

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>messages</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param> 
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:/application-context.xml
            classpath:/application-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Predefined pages -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <!--    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>-->
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/404.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ServletException</exception-type>
        <location>/index.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
        <location>/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- MIME TYPES -->
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>css</extension>
        <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>  
        <extension>eot</extension>  
        <mime-type>application/x-font-eot</mime-type>  
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>js</extension>
        <mime-type>text/javascript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>latex</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-latex</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>  
        <extension>otf</extension>  
        <mime-type>application/x-font-opentype</mime-type>  
    </mime-mapping>   
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>roff</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-troff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>  
        <extension>svg</extension>  
        <mime-type>application/svg+xml</mime-type>  
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>  
        <extension>ttf</extension>  
        <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>  
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>  
        <extension>woff</extension>  
        <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>  
    </mime-mapping> 
    <mime-mapping>  
        <extension>woff2</extension>  
        <mime-type>application/x-font-woff2</mime-type>  
    </mime-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Using GlassFish 4.1, spring framework version 4.1.2.RELEASE, and spring security version 3.2.5.RELEASE.

I would appreciate every answer. This error already took two days without any solutions :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have CRLF protection enabled at .

You can try to support CRLF by adding this to your form:

```
<input type="hidden"
    name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
    value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

If that doesn't work, you can remove CSRF - although that's not recommended.

More information: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf

Answer (score 0):

Using spring url taglig or jstl url taglib to write down your url. [This post](http://devjav.com/spring-security-using-jdbc-authentication/) is good for learn spring security configure